# Bones larger after exporting as FBX

Tags: export, bones, transforms, .fbx

I have a mesh that I have rigged with 3 bones but when I export it as FBX, the bones somehow become much bigger I cannot figure out what the problem is. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to correct this. I have attached the screenshot of the original & exported mesh as well as the export settings just let me know if you need any more information.[image: The Original]
[image: Exported FBX]
[image: Export Settings]

Comment: the problem appears to be that fbx export followed by fbx import is broken.  I think you've run into a bug.  If you hover over the ! in triangle next to Apply Transform you'll get a warning to that effect.

Comment: But I've tried exporting with Apply Transform disabled and it didn't fix the problem.